# How to protect ajax requests in Laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel, security, laravel-5

I use ajax to store, update and delete resources associated with authenticated user. Routes for these actions use `web` middleware so cookies, session etc are available. Project is based on Laravel framework.

Is it necessary to protect those routes from unauthorized access in any additional way? I've read about API tokens that one could use, but I am not sure if it is necessary.

I will be grateful for any insights on ajax security or how ajax requests work in general, as it is a little over my head at this moment.

Comment: Introduction to this [article](https://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs) helped me a lot in understanding use case for token authentication: basically multi-platform, distributed systems where it is hard to maintain session across the board. It might be a good idea to couple frontend and backend already using tokens so it is easier to scale later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say no additional work is necessary assuming you have appropriate checks in place such as a user can't delete another user's entities, etc...

AJAX requests are really just like the user browsing to different pages except it's javascript making requests on their behalf.  Since everything is already behind the `web` middleware, there should be no need for additional authentication since your users have technically already logged in.

Answer (score 2):

Look for [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/)

> What is JSON Web Token?
>
> JSON Web Token (JWT) is an open standard (RFC 7519) that defines a
>   compact and self-contained way for securely transmitting information
>   between parties as a JSON object. This information can be verified and
>   trusted because it is digitally signed. JWTs can be signed using a
>   secret (with the HMAC algorithm) or a public/private key pair using
>   RSA.

and this article:

[Authenticate users in Node using JWT and Laravel](https://dotdev.co/authenticate-laravel-5-user-account-in-nodejs-socket-io-using-json-web-tokens-jwt-f74009d612f8#.2g25iklqh)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I know about jwt, there is even dedicated package for Laravel https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth, however is it necessary? If possible (and safe) I would prefer to save me some time and use built in functionality, even if it won't be the fanciest solution.